# IMCE button not showing despite profiles already set

Tags: drupal

I am trying to set up CkEditor to upload images using IMCE. I have enabled the module and set the permissions for each profile:[image: IMCE profiles]

CkEditor is using IMCE [image: CkEditor settings]

However, the upload button is not shown in the toolbar when I try to upload a new image:[image: Toolbar]

I would like to upload them to my ./drupal/uploads/images/ directory, so I supose that it would be /uploads/images, am I right? If so, those directories have already 777 permissions.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using JQuery 1.9 which does not have the Jquery.Browser object and that made it to broke some modules, including IMCE and Wysiwyg...